# ¿Cuál es el origen del "pasado mañana"?

Tags: etimología, tiempo

Si "pasado" significa una vez anterior, y "mañana" es el día siguiente, ¿cómo llegamos a que "pasado mañana" sea "el día que sigue a mañana"?

¿O "pasado" también tiene un significado similar a "past" en inglés, para significar "beyond"?

¿Puedo decir, análogamente, "pasado mes", "pasado año" para el mes o el año que viene?

Comment: Efectivamente: “Pasado el pueblo encontrarás la gasolinera”. “Pasado mañana será miércoles”.

Comment: **Pasado** del verbo [pasar](https://dle.rae.es/pasar#S33P1kX) significa «Ir más allá de un punto limitado o determinado» **Pasado mañana** es «más allá de mañana»

Comment: @DGaleano Entonces "pasado mes" es el mes que viene, no?

Comment: No, you have to have something definite that it has gone past as in the two examples that @aerobiomat gave you.

Comment: Casi.............. _**Pasado** el/este mes espero que ya haya pasado la pandemia_ = _**El mes que viene** espero haya pasado la pandemia_

Comment: @DGaleano es el "casi" que me interesa.  "pasado mañana será martes" es bueno, pero "pasado mes será septiembre" no es.   Me parece que "Pasado el/este mes .." es un concepto diferente.

Comment: Si miras pasado como **verbo** en el enlace que te dejé antes ves que es *transitivo* y necesitas usar un **complemento directo** o sea un objeto definido. Puedes decir sin problema «_**Pasado septiembre** volveremos a la normalidad_» , pero *pasado mes* no.

Comment: Esta serie de comentarios indica que la pregunta es más que válida. Retiro mi voto de cerrar. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Pasado mañana" es una locución adverbial que, a mi entender, puede interpretarse como proveniente de una construcción absoluta:

- Habiendo pasado mañana (Tomorrow having passed), estaremos a salvo.
- Pasado mañana (Tomorrow having passed), estaremos a salvo.

La frase se ha lexicalizado como un adverbio, pero el participio "pasado" puede usarse en otras frases temporales:

- Pasado el invierno (The winter over), llegará la primavera.
- Pasado el 2020 (2020 having finished), encontraremos la vacuna.
- Pasado el día del examen (The day of the exam having been left behind), te sentirás más tranquilo.

Comment: Gracias.  Lo entiendo ahora. 2 llaves para mí son que "mañana" es adverbial, y que "mes" y "año" son substantivos.  Y otra llave es que cuando pensando en inglés no pensé así "Tomorrow having passed".

Comment: Exactamente. Los sustantivos "mes" y "año" pueden ir acompañados de un demostrativo y, en ese caso, adquieren valor adverbial: *Este año no saldré de vacaciones pero pasado este año haré un viaje.*

Answer (score 0):

Por añadir algo más a la [respuesta de Gustavson](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/35542/12637), comentar que en un principio no se usaba *mañana* con el sentido de "el día que sigue al de hoy", sino con el sentido de "primera hora del día". El siguiente texto es de aproximadamente el año 1300:

> *E depues que el sol entrare, qualquier que las guardas fallaren de noche andando por las calles, metanle en el cepo **fasta la mannana**. E quando fuere de dia, trayan le a conceio [...].*

Con el tiempo la palabra *mañana* se convirtió en un adverbio y se empezaron a usar frases como "el rey vendrá mañana", y de ahí surgió la locución adverbial "pasado mañana" para referirse al día que vendrá una vez haya *pasado* el día de mañana. El primer caso que encuentro en el CORDE es el siguiente:

> *[...] porque todas las cosas están aparejadas, pasando mañana se hará, y byen me pareçe que aquel rreyno no esté syn cabeça ny señor.*
>
> Anónimo, "La corónica de Adramón", c 1492 (España).

Nótese el uso de "pasando mañana", empleando el gerundio en lugar del participio. Durante el siglo XVI se alternó en textos "pasando mañana" y "pasado mañana", con preferencia de esta segunda opción, posiblemente por su mayor facilidad de pronunciación. En todo caso no era una expresión muy usada todavía, apenas 15 casos en todo el siglo XVI.